# C# .net regex extracting a string from within a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a string output that looks like this:

```
ID       = GC5c.U.feab4bc5-8-92e-c486eaddddf8
AESKEY1  = efbf5c9db259e345c205b0da27f6fb459D
AESKEY2  = ea85af9f1e5f42ff4fe8b9f07e7dcebc68
DESKEY1  = 6388a9e1a2fc8981189f0f412ae4e8

ID       = JNPa.T.71664548-82-be2-a51aadd4a6f3
AESKEY1  = 37af9242c8879414e420f46903c16adebd3
AESKEY2  = 1259a1f6f6da03cb3984a117ca617d9ff73
DESKEY1  = 9547dc08db70cb95789f3a59e5c6adebd31
```

How can I iterate through the ID(s) of this list and obtain the values within the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file, iterate through each line, and put it into a `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/YourFilePath.txt"))
{    
   while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
   {
        string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split('=');
        data.Add(line[0].TrimEnd(), line[1].TrimStart());
   }
}
```

UPDATE: Note that this solution is using Dictionary, and so it does not allow duplicate keys. If you need to duplicate keys, I would suggest changing this solution for a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. The code will get a little dirtier by the way:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/YourFilePath.txt"))
{    
   while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
   {
        string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split('=');
        data.Add(new KeyValuePair(line[0].TrimEnd(), line[1].TrimStart()));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure `Regex` is the best suited for this scenario, however, please find below a solution using it with a named group `"id"`.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"id.*=\s*(?<id>.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var input = @"ID       = Gs3c.H.feab4bc5-6c00-4ee8-9e2e-c486eaddddf8
              AESKEY1  = efbf5c9db259e345c205b0da27f6fb459D
              AESKEY2  = ea85af9f1e5f42ff4fe8b9f07e7dcebc68
              DESKEY1  = 6388a9e1a2fc8981189f0f412ae4e8

              ID       = JNPa.T.71664548-82-be2-a51aadd4a6f3
              AESKEY1  = 37af9242c8879414e420f46903c16adebd3
              AESKEY2  = 1259a1f6f6da03cb3984a117ca617d9ff73
              DESKEY1  = 9547dc08db70cb95789f3a59e5c6adebd31";

var ids = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["id"]);
```

Here is the Regex test: [Regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=id.*%3D%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cid%3E.*%29&i=ID%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20Gs3c.H.feab4bc5-6c00-4ee8-9e2e-c486eaddddf8%0D%0AAESKEY1%20%20%3D%20efbf5c9db259e345c205b0da27f6fb459D%0D%0AAESKEY2%20%20%3D%20ea85af9f1e5f42ff4fe8b9f07e7dcebc68%0D%0ADESKEY1%20%20%3D%206388a9e1a2fc8981189f0f412ae4e8%0D%0A%0D%0AID%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20JNPa.T.71664548-82-be2-a51aadd4a6f3%0D%0AAESKEY1%20%20%3D%2037af9242c8879414e420f46903c16adebd3%0D%0AAESKEY2%20%20%3D%201259a1f6f6da03cb3984a117ca617d9ff73%0D%0ADESKEY1%20%20%3D%209547dc08db70cb95789f3a59e5c6adebd31&o=i)

Answer (score 0):

NicoRiff's suggestion of using regular parsing into a `Dictionary` is the way to go. Here's the obligatory LINQ-based approach:

```
var data = File.ReadLines("C:/your/file/path.txt")
               .Select(l => l.Split('='))
               .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);
```

**EDIT:** As Nico pointed out, when the dictionary is going to contain duplicate keys, then a dictionary won't work. However, you can still use LINQ to automatically arrange the dictionary so that the ID field of your source text is the key instead of the field names. For example, you can use the following:

```
var data = File.ReadLines("C:/your/file/path.txt")
               .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
               .Select((l, i) => new { ID = i / 4, Value = l.Split('=') })
               .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
               .Select(g => new { ID = g.First().Value[1].Trim(), Values = g.ToDictionary(k => k.Value[0].Trim(), v => v.Value[1].Trim()) })
               .ToDictionary(k => k.ID, v => v.Values);
```

Afterwards, you can iterate through `data` to get your fields:

```
foreach (var d in data.Values)
{
    string id = d["ID"];
    string aesKey1 = d["AESKEY1"];
    string aesKey2 = d["AESKEY2"];
    string desKey1 = d["DESKEY1"];
}
```

Comment: At first it seems that Dictionary was the way to go to solve this one. But it seems that OP needs to have duplicate keys inside the dictionary so I assume that wont work. I edited my answer to give a useful workaround on this one.

Comment: @NicoRiff I'm working on a solution to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to put the data into a dictionary like: `Dicationary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>`
Where the `key` of the main dictionary is the value of ID, and the internal dictionaries are the values that follows, then the following would do it:

```
string[] lines = input.Split('\n');
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>();
var currentKey = "";

foreach (string[] keyVal in lines.Where(line=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                                 .Select(line => line.Split('='))) 
{
    if (keyVal[0].StartsWith("ID"))
    {
        currentKey = keyVal[1].Trim();
        myDict.Add(currentKey, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    }
    else
    {
        myDict[currentKey].Add(keyVal[0].Trim(), keyVal[1].Trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Regex would look like so:

```
@"^ID\s+=\s+(.+)$"
```

You can test it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uiOzkv/1) and [Rextester](http://rextester.com/OGTV15439)